# Android Studio RssFeed

Tags: android

I'm writing an rssfeed with android studio I'm using an emulator.  My code compiles and launches but it doesn't show anything on the screen except the title MyRssFeed on the top.  Is there something I'm missing?

**Class:**

```
package jrodriguez.myrssfeed;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

/**
* Created by Jennifer Rodriguez on 3/8/2016.
*/
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private TextView src;


protected void OnCreate(Bundle SavedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(SavedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    src = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
}

public void fetch(View v) {
    Downloader d = new Downloader();
    d.execute("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page");
    try {
        src.setText(d.get());

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Error to thread", e.toString());
    }
}

class Downloader extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        String result = null;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(urls[0]);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            InputStream in = conn.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                result = result + line;
            }
            conn.disconnect();
            reader.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("error to fetching", e.toString());
        }
        return result;
    }


}
```

**XML file**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res
 /android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:enabled="true" />

    <Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/Fetch"
    android:id="@+id/Fetch"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:clickable="true" />
   </LinearLayout>
```

**Manifest**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="jrodriguez.myrssfeed">

    <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
         </activity>
    <uses-permissions android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    </application>
    </manifest>
```

Comment: Implement clickListener for Button. Then only your fetch() will work.

Comment: add this line in you xml file within button tag android:onClick="fetch". actually you fetch(View v) function is not executing. try this maybe it shows what you want

Comment: My button isn't showing when it launches

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make the following changes.

```
Button btn;

protected void OnCreate(Bundle SavedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(SavedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    src = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
    btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Fetch);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                       fetch();
            }
        });
}

public void fetch() {
 //
}
```

Comment: I did need that as well but I am still having the same problem with nothing showing up when I launch.  I do have a warning that says my onCreate is never being used?  Could this be the problem?

Comment: the xml file that you have pasted here , is that your xml for activity_main ? Try to directly run in an android device than emulator and see.